# jquery insert data into next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am displaying data in table as below

```
{'headers': [u'first',
             u'last',
             u'age'],
 'values': [[u'sam',u'tom', 31]]}
```

using jquery as

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    for (var i = 0; i<value.length; i++){
        if (index=="headers"){
            tr.append("<th>" + value[i] + "</th>");
        }
        else{
            for (var j = 0; j<value[i].length; j++){
                tr.append("<td>" + value[i][j] + "</td>");
            }
        }
    }

    $("#table1").append(tr);
});
```

And it displays properly with header row and first row. But when I have data with 2 values list as

```
 'values': [[u'sam', u'tom', 31],
            [u'dean', u'tom', 28]]
```

rather that creating second row it displays whole 6 values in one row. 
How can get second list to display in next row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a new row for each array in `values`:

```js
var data = {
  'headers': ['first','last','age'],
  'values': [
    ['sam','tom', 31],
    ['johnny','walker', 69]
  ]
}
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  if (index == "headers") {
    let tr = $('<tr />');
    $.each(value, function(k, v){
      tr.append("<th>" + v + "</th>");
    })
    $("#table1").append(tr);
  } else {
    $.each(value, function(i,row) {
      let tr = $('<tr />');
      $.each(row, function(k, v){
        tr.append("<td>" + v + "</td>");
      })
      $("#table1").append(tr);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1"></table>
```

Comment: when i'm ruuning I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in..`

Comment: @user2661518 Ah, I know what it is. I wrongly renamed the `headers` to `header`. My bad. Sorry. Fixed now. :)

Comment: Make sure the key in your data is the same as the one checked in the condition: `header` / `headers`. When I initially wrote the script I named it `header` by mistake, and you probably have that in your script now. Copy paste the script again.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your rows before adding anything to them with `<tr/>`

Try this:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i<value.length; i++){
        if (index=="headers"){
            tr.append("<th>" + value[i] + "</th>");
        }
        else{
            for (var j = 0; j<value[i].length; j++){
                tr.append("<td>" + value[i][j] + "</td>");
            }
            tr.append("</tr><tr>");
        }
    }
    tr.append("</tr>");
    $("#table1").append(tr);
});
```

Comment: I tried this, I added `tr.append("</tr>");` this line as per above, but still getting results in same row

Comment: I updated tr as well  as per `var tr = $('<tr>');` but still getting same
`

Comment: I have edited the answer - try that. You need a new row after each data array is rendered.

Comment: hmm same result

Comment: Welcome to [so], Nik. You've got two errors: 1) You're trying to append `</tr><tr>`. You can only append markup that validates as tags. 2) You're not creating a clean row for each iteration inside your `for` values.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, I'll step out of this. I thought we were just appending strings - I'll go and read up.

Comment: It's actually not [`that clear`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). They say `HTML string`. What they meant is: a string that can be parsed into valid `HTML`. And it makes sense, if you think about it. You're welcome. Heh, [`found it`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString).